# Installing OpenStack with Landscape Autopilot fails to parse http

Tags: maas, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot, orange-box

I'm trying to install `OpenStack` with `Landscape` using an `Orange Box`, and am following these instructions to set up landscape [from here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack). I already have a `MaaS` environment running on the machine (it's an Orange Box), and enter `http:// 10.14.4.1/MAAS/` as the MAAS server IP, along with the correct API key. However, the installation fails and in `~/.cloud-install/commands.log` it says `failed to parse http:`. [Here](http://pastebin.com/M3mSv6Sa) is the full log . Does anyone know why this is happening? Thank you.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out - it just wanted the IP not the full URL. Problem solved by entering 10.14.4.1 instead of http://10.14.4.1/MAAS

Answer (score 2):

OP posted:

It just wanted the IP not the full URL. Problem solved by entering `10.14.4.1` instead of `10.14.4.1/MAAS`